# Building a Spring Boot project using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jsp, model-view-controller, spring-boot

**Update:**

Thanks all for your answer. I still have problems, since it's not returning the result I hoped. Is it a problem of the placement of the files? They are organized like this: [i63.tinypic.com/2by8g2.png](http://i63.tinypic.com/2by8g2.png)

Thanks again in advance.

---

I'm studying in order to create a web application using Spring Boot and JDBC (without JPA); I'm having several problems doing it.
I don't understand how to correctly create the controller, and how to make it return the .jsp pages that I want.
I searched lots and lots solutions, but just can't find the right one.
This is my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>---myprojectname</groupId>
    <artifactId>tesieasy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>tesieasy</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My application.properties:

```
> spring.h2.console.enabled=true
server.port=8000
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

My ServetInizializer:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TesieasyApplication.class);
    }

}
```

My entity:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Journal {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Date created;
    private String summary;
    private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    /** costruttori**/
    public Journal() {}

    public Journal(Long id, String title, String summary, Date date){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.created = date;
    }

    /** getters and setters omitted **/
```

My service:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import name of my package-.entity.Journal;


@Service
public class JournalService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JournalService.class);

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void insertData() {
        log.info("> Table creation");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE JOURNAL IF EXISTS");
        jdbcTemplate
                .execute("-cut for brevity-");
        log.info("> Done.");
    }

    public List<Journal> findAll() {
        List<Journal> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        jdbcTemplate
                .query("SELECT * FROM JOURNAL",
                        new Object[] {}, (rs, row) -> new Journal(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("title"),
                                rs.getString("summary"), new Date(rs.getTimestamp("created").getTime())))
                .forEach(entry -> entries.add(entry));
        return entries;

    }

        public int countEntries() {
        int rowCount = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT count(*) FROM JOURNAL", Integer.class);
        return rowCount;

    }

    public Journal insertJournal() {
        Journal journal = null;
        this.jdbcTemplate.update(
                -cut for brevity-");
        return journal;

    }
}
```

One of my .jsp pages:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>A title</title></head>
<body>
Hello! JSP is working fine!
</body>
</html>
```

And finally my controller:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import *my package name.entity.Journal;
import *my package name.service.JournalService;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private JournalService journalService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String home() {
    return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/findAll")
    public String index() {
        List<Journal> all;
        all = journalService.findAll();
        return all.toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/count")
    public int countElements() {
        int count;
        count = journalService.countEntries();
        return count;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/insert")
    public Journal insertElements() {
        Journal insert;
        insert = journalService.insertJournal();
        return insert;
    }

}
```

What I understood:

- I don't need a web.xml file
- How to connect the service with the controller (even if my findAll method return my data into {}, and I have to understand how to write it properly)

What I don't understand:

- Why it's not linking correctly to my JSP pages - what do I need?
- Do I need a Model and View?

I hope you can give me some advice and/or some examples right for my scope.
Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: @RestController should not be used to return view. Although there may be means to return view using it, fundamentally its incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Step1: change the @RestController to @Controller

Step2: for URL that you want to return a view (e.g. greeting.jsp)

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting() {
    return "greeting";
}
```

Step3: for URL that you want to return a JSON object, no view (perhaps an AJAX call)

```
@RequestMapping("/findAll")
@ResponseBody
public List<Journal> index() {
    List<Journal> all = journalService.findAll()
    return all;
}
```

OR this

```
@RequestMapping("/findAll")
@ResponseBody
public Model index(Model model) {
    List<Journal> all =journalService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("journalList", all);
    return model;
}
```

Step4: for URL that you want the view and the model (e.g. a java object)

> ref Rob Baily sample code

```
@RequestMapping("/findAll")
public String index(Model model) {
    List<Journal> all;
    all = journalService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("journalList", all);
    return "listall";
}
```

and you can access the object in your listall.jsp by using ${journalList}

Explanation:
When you use @RestController on your class, it is equivalent to adding @ResponseBody for every method in your class. Thus, it will always return an object.toString() on the page and not linking to your JSP.

> This code uses Spring 4’s new @RestController annotation, which marks the class as a controller where every method returns a domain object instead of a view. It’s shorthand for @Controller and @ResponseBody rolled together.
>   ref: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

jsp sample reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have problems, since it's not returning the result I hoped. Is it a problem of the placement of the files? They are organized like this: http://i63.tinypic.com/2by8g2.png

Comment: hi, tina, I unable to view the link (I do not know why). according to your application.properties file, your jsp should be in webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/{myPage}.jsp. If access the url: http://localhost:8080/greeting, it will be looking for WEB-INF/jsp/greeting.jsp.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment points out RestController is not correct if you want to return a view to be rendered.  A RestController returns the object as JSON rather that an id for a view which is used for AJAX requests.  Just use the Controller annotation if you want to return a view.

You do not need a View as it should route the return value to the JSP page.  If you want to use JSP tags then yes you will need a Model and you will need to add objects to your Model object.  See the example below.  The first method should go to welcome.jsp and have no model available.  The second method should go to listall.jsp and make a journalList attribute available for use in JSP tags.

```
@Controller
 public class ApplicationController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/findAll")
    public String index(Model model) {
        List<Journal> all;
        all = journalService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("journalList", all);
        return "listall";
    }
}
```